# How to create a command that shows all directories, through a shell script?

Tags: shell, directory, command, sh, command-line-arguments

I'd like to create a command that shows all directories in the directory given as a parameter. For example, if our file hierarchy is as such :

```
dir1:
    dir2
    dir3
    file1
    dir4:
        file2
        dir5
```

Then the result of `rep dir1` should show :

```
dir2
dir3
dir4
```

Whereas `rep dir1/dir4` should show :

```
dir5
```

At the moment I have a shell script `rep.sh` doing the following :

```
function rep(){
    all=`ls $1`
    for each in $all
    do 
        if [ -d $each ]
        then
            echo $each
        fi
    done
}
```

Executing this script through `bash rep.sh` doesn't do anything, which I assume is correct, but then when I do `rep dir1` or `rep dir1/dir4` it doesn't show anything. I think my error lies with me not using the function environment correctly, or me not passing arguments correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three errors :

1) usage of

```
all=`ls $1`
```

instead of

```
all="$1"/*
```

which @Benjamin W. pointed out.

2) I forgot to put `rep $1` at the end of my `rep.sh` file. The file thus looks like :

```
function rep(){
    all="$1"/*    
    for each in $all
    do 
        if [ -d $each ]
        then
            echo $each
        fi
    done
}

rep $1
```

3) In the command line, I need to put `alias rep="bash rep.sh"` to be able to use the command `rep` freely in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [`basename`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) for that.

```
...
find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \;
...
```

The options `-mindepth 1` and `-maxdepth 1` prevent listing the base directory or descending into the sub directories. `-type d` applies a filter so that only directories are listed and `-exec basename {} \;` executes `basename` for the found item. `basename` strips the path so that only the directory name itself is printed.

Comment: Allthough this might be a suitable answer, I'd like to find the error in my already existant rep.sh file.

Answer (score 1):

In pure Bash:

```sh
rep() {
    for dir in "$1"/*/; do
        dir=${dir%/}
        printf '%s\n' "${dir##*/}"
    done
}
```

The glob `"$1"/*/` gets all directories; the two parameter expansions then remove the trailing slash and the path to the directories.

This ignores hidden directories; if you want these as well, you have to turn on the `dotglob` shell option. To preserve the setting of that shell option, you can wrap the function like this:

```sh
rep() {
    local dg
    # Get current dotglob setting
    dg=$(shopt -p dotglob)
    # Enable dotglob
    shopt -s dotglob
    for dir in "$1"/*/; do
        dir=${dir%/}
        printf '%s\n' "${dir##*/}"
    done
    # Set dotglob back to what it was
    $dg
}
```

---

As for why your script isn't working: have a look at what's contained in `all` after you assign to it.

```
$ all=$(ls "$1")
$ declare -p all
declare -- all="dir2
dir3
dir4
file1"
```

(Notice that I've also replaced the obsolete backticks with `$()` and double quoted `$1`.)

The output of `ls` doesn't contain the paths to the directories, that's why your `-d` test returns false for everything.

Using `ls` the way you do is very error prone: word splitting and parameter expansion make such a script fail for any filename with a blank or a shell metacharacter (see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls(1)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)). Use globs instead.

Comment: This doesn't work. When I do bash rep.sh, and then rep dir1 it doesn't show anything, do I need to do something else?

Comment: @J.Schmidt You have to *source* the file containing the function first: `. rep.sh`, then use the function, `rep dir1`.